Change a paragraph style based on the paragraph style before it
In InDesign, I have H1, H2, and H3 styles that look fine when preceded and followed by my Body style. But in the instances where H1 is followed by H2, or H2 is followed by H3, there is too much white space between the heads.
I'm hoping there is a way to add a GREP style that can address this either by changing the baseline shift or the leading of the whole paragraph.
So for H2, if the preceding paragraph style is H1, set the baseline shift of the whole H2 paragraph to +6pt, or set the leading to 110% instead of 120.
I'm so used to being able to do this type of thing in CSS! I don't want to have to create special styles "H2 immediately after H1" and "H3 immediately after H2".

Hi and welcome to GDSE! I've voted to close your question because I think it has a duplicate - not because it's bad. Take a look at the other question. The answer I give there is sadly that you have to make those additional styles you don't want to make. Styles in InDesign isn't like CSS, so it's easiest to just accept that. Perhaps there could be a specific solution in your case, but it depends on how your styles look.

GREP style won't be able to fix this. It uses GREP search to select parts within a paragraph and apply some Character Style to them. It can't search outside the paragraph and check what comes before/after.

InDesign padding doesn't work like CSS padding.

@Wolff I had come up with a similar solution to your recommendation. I don't like it because it complicates styles (I also need to update my TOC to allow the new styles). I also have to go through the document and manually apply the styles. I like the notion of the GREP style changing things automatically. Now to decide whether to implement this or just live with the wider spacing.

Hmm, I see the problem with TOC. Would it work if you left the heading styles as they are and introduced a "Body last" style with space after instead?

That seems more reasonable. I’ll try that out; I have a document where this happens several times.
